# Can't install haskell package http-enumerator

Tags: haskell, hackage

Got the following bash transcript when run cabal install.

It looks it complainted many packages required by http-enumerator is not available. I am not sure what "Backjump" mean in the last line of the printout.

How do I resolve the package dependencies?

```
$ cabal install http-enumerator
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
trying: http-enumerator-0.7.3.3 (user goal)
next goal: asn1-data (dependency of http-enumerator-0.7.3.3)
rejecting: asn1-data-0.7.1, 0.7.0 (conflict: http-enumerator =>
asn1-data>=0.5.1 && <0.7)
trying: asn1-data-0.6.1.3
next goal: text (dependency of asn1-data-0.6.1.3)
rejecting: text-1.2.0.0/installed-18f... (conflict: text =>
bytestring==0.10.4.0/installed-6da..., http-enumerator => bytestring>=0.9.1.4
&& <0.10)
trying: text-1.2.0.4
next goal: certificate (dependency of http-enumerator-0.7.3.3)
rejecting: certificate-1.3.9, 1.3.8, 1.3.7, 1.3.6, 1.3.5, 1.3.3, 1.3.2, 1.3.1,
1.3.0, 1.2.9, 1.2.8, 1.2.7, 1.2.6, 1.2.5, 1.2.4, 1.2.3, 1.2.2, 1.2.1, 1.2.0
(conflict: http-enumerator => certificate>=1.1 && <1.2)
trying: certificate-1.1.1
next goal: tls-extra (dependency of http-enumerator-0.7.3.3)
rejecting: tls-extra-0.6.6, 0.6.5, 0.6.4, 0.6.3, 0.6.1, 0.6.0, 0.5.1, 0.5.0
(conflict: http-enumerator => tls-extra>=0.4.3 && <0.5)
rejecting: tls-extra-0.4.7.1, 0.4.7, 0.4.6.1, 0.4.6, 0.4.5 (conflict:
certificate==1.1.1, tls-extra => certificate>=1.2.0 && <1.3.0)
rejecting: tls-extra-0.4.4, 0.4.3 (conflict: text==1.2.0.4, tls-extra =>
text>=0.5 && <1.0)
rejecting: tls-extra-0.4.2.1, 0.4.2, 0.4.1, 0.4.0, 0.3.1, 0.3.0, 0.2.3, 0.2.2,
0.2.1, 0.2.0, 0.1.9, 0.1.8, 0.1.7, 0.1.6, 0.1.5, 0.1.4, 0.1.3, 0.1.2, 0.1.1,
0.1.0 (conflict: http-enumerator => tls-extra>=0.4.3 && <0.5)
Backjump limit reached (change with --max-backjumps).
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you don't find any other solution: rm -rf ~/.ghc ~/.cabal

Comment: Welcome to [cabal hell](https://www.google.com/search?q=cabal+hell).

Comment: Did you even tried add options cabal suggests ? For unlimited tries put `-1` to backjumps and see if it does help. Reorder goals is a recommended combination in such case. So install command would look like`cabal install --max-backjumps=-1 --reorder-goals <pkg-name>`

Comment: Hi David, can you explain a bit more on "--reorder-goals"? I have minimal experience with cabal.

Comment: you should use ssandboxes

Comment: That library has been deprecated in favor of http-conduit and http-client. I'd recommend trying those, which shouldn't have such issues.

Answer (score 1):

In general, this sort of problem happens because you're trying to install package `A`, which depends (directly or indirectly) on package `B`. However, you already have package `C` installed, which also depends on package `B`, but the version of `B` that `C` was linked with won't work with `A`.

In some cases you might be able to resolve this sort of problem using:

```
cabal install --max-backjumps=-1 --reorder-goals <pkg-name>
```

...but that only works sometimes. A cleaner way to address this sort of thing is to use [sandboxes](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/installing-packages.html#developing-with-sandboxes). This will help if you don't need both `A` and `C` in the same sandbox, or you can re-link `C` with a different version of `B`. You can do what you want in the sandbox without messing up your main Haskell installation.

If you've written `A` or `C` yourself, you may need to examine the dependencies of your packages and make adjustments. I'm going translate part of that output into English, to give you an example of how to diagnose dependency problems.

```
$ cabal install http-enumerator
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
trying: http-enumerator-0.7.3.3 (user goal)
```

You requested `http-enumerator`. The latest version is 0.7.3.3, so I'll try to install that.

```
next goal: asn1-data (dependency of http-enumerator-0.7.3.3)
```

Now, `http-enumerator-0.7.3.3` requires the package `asn1-data`, so let me try to install that.

```
rejecting: asn1-data-0.7.1, 0.7.0 (conflict: http-enumerator =>
asn1-data>=0.5.1 && <0.7)
```

The latest two versions of `asn1-data` are 0.7.1 and 0.7.0. But `http-enumerator-0.7.3.3` requires an earlier version of `asn1-data`. So let me try an older version of `asn1-data`

```
trying: asn1-data-0.6.1.3
```

The next available version of `asn1-data` is 0.6.1.3.

```
next goal: text (dependency of asn1-data-0.6.1.3)
```

But that version of `asn1-data` requires `text`, so I need to install that first.

```
rejecting: text-1.2.0.0/installed-18f... (conflict: text =>
bytestring==0.10.4.0/installed-6da..., http-enumerator => bytestring>=0.9.1.4
&& <0.10)
```

The latest version of `text` is 1.2.0.0, but that won't work because it needs a different version of `bytestring` than `http-enumerator` wants. So let me try an older version of `text`.

```
trying: text-1.2.0.4
next goal: certificate (dependency of http-enumerator-0.7.3.3)
```

Now, that version of `text` requires `certificate`, so I need to install that first.

```
rejecting: certificate-1.3.9, 1.3.8, 1.3.7, 1.3.6, 1.3.5, 1.3.3, 1.3.2, 1.3.1,
1.3.0, 1.2.9, 1.2.8, 1.2.7, 1.2.6, 1.2.5, 1.2.4, 1.2.3, 1.2.2, 1.2.1, 1.2.0
(conflict: http-enumerator => certificate>=1.1 && <1.2)
```

But all these versions of `certificate` are incompatible with `http-enumerator`.

```
trying: certificate-1.1.1
```

Finally a bit of success. I can use `certificate-1.1.1`, and satisfy all of the dependencies of `asn1-data` `text`.

```
next goal: tls-extra (dependency of http-enumerator-0.7.3.3)
```

But `http-enumerator-0.7.3.3` also requires `tls-extra`.

```
rejecting: tls-extra-0.6.6, 0.6.5, 0.6.4, 0.6.3, 0.6.1, 0.6.0, 0.5.1, 0.5.0
(conflict: http-enumerator => tls-extra>=0.4.3 && <0.5)
```

We can't use the latest versions of `tls-extra` because they are incompatible with `http-enumerator`.

```
rejecting: tls-extra-0.4.7.1, 0.4.7, 0.4.6.1, 0.4.6, 0.4.5 (conflict:
certificate==1.1.1, tls-extra => certificate>=1.2.0 && <1.3.0)
```

We can't use these versions of `tls-extra` because they are incompatible with `certificate`.

```
rejecting: tls-extra-0.4.4, 0.4.3 (conflict: text==1.2.0.4, tls-extra =>
text>=0.5 && <1.0)
```

We can't use these versions of `tls-extra` because they are incompatible with `text`.

```
rejecting: tls-extra-0.4.2.1, 0.4.2, 0.4.1, 0.4.0, 0.3.1, 0.3.0, 0.2.3, 0.2.2,
0.2.1, 0.2.0, 0.1.9, 0.1.8, 0.1.7, 0.1.6, 0.1.5, 0.1.4, 0.1.3, 0.1.2, 0.1.1,
0.1.0 (conflict: http-enumerator => tls-extra>=0.4.3 && <0.5)
```

And older versions of `tls-extra` aren't compatible with `http-enumerator`.

```
Backjump limit reached (change with --max-backjumps).
```

I give up!